# Can i start and stop listening to emit method from child's component EventEmitter in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

Just like the title, i have the need to stop listening to child's component output EventEmitter after certain condition, but i need to start listening to it again.
So, how do i do that exactly?
I've read about bad practice using subscribe() and unsubscribe() from EventEmitter since there's chance EventEmitter won't support it in the future.

Comment: it is better you go for shred services [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq) question 2

Comment: From where 'comes' the condition? from the parent or the child?

Comment: @Vega from the parent

Comment: @Vega no. i used another approach. but thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add that condition as a new child's attribute:

**Parent HTML**

```
<child [conditionForChild]="myCondition" ......></child>
```

**Parent Typescript**

```
conditionForChild: boolean; // set it as needed afterwards
```

**Child typescript:**

```
 @Input() conditionForChild; 
  ....
  action($event) { //this is your existing method which will emit the event to the parent
     if(conditionForChild){
       this.action.emit();
     }
  }
```

Or:

```
<child (action)="condition? delete() : null" ......> </child>
```